# Print an array and stops when it finds a specified string with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loop to print snack until it finds fsnack.

```
snack = ['tomatos', 'lettuce', 'candles', 'books', 'cables', 'oreo', 'banana']
fsnack = 'oreo'

for number, letter in enumerate(snack, 1):
    print (number, letter)
    if(snack == fsnack):
        break
```

This is the exercise I'm trying to do:

[image: this is the exercise I'm trying to do]

this is my first post here!!

Comment: Use ```enumerate(snack)```, not ```enumerate(snack, 1)```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: `letter` isn't a very good variable name for the food item you're trying to compare to `fsnack`.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi - That would start the index at 0 where the op appears to be trying to print from 1.

Comment: You have a list named `snack` that you're trying to compare to a string `fsnack`.  This comparison will always be false.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: For your bonus points, get rid of the for loop and just use `next(s for s in snack if s ==  fsnack)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing `fsnack` to `snack` (which is the list), you need to compare it with `letter` (which represents a value of the list):

```
snack = ['tomatos', 'lettuce', 'candles', 'books', 'cables', 'oreo', 'banana']
fsnack = 'oreo'

for number, letter in enumerate(snack, 1):
    print (number, letter)
    if(letter == fsnack):
        break
```

Output :

```
1 tomatos
2 lettuce
3 candles
4 books
5 cables
6 oreo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
snacks = ['tomatos', 'lettuce', 'candles', 'books', 'cables', 'oreo', 'banana']
fsnack = 'oreo'

for index, snack in enumerate(snacks):

   print("{}, {}".format(index, snack))
   if(snack == fsnack): break
```

The assignment also asks if you can do this without a break. This is a possible solution:

```
try:
    fsnack_index = snacks.index('oreo')
    for i in range(0, fsnack_index+1):
       print("{}, {}".format(i, snacks[i]))
except ValueError:
    print("No oreos")
```

What we do is use the index function native to python, that looks for the index location of your snack.

We can then use a standard range for loop and just print up until the oreo. The reason why we add +1 to the index, is because the upper bound of the for loop range is exclusive, not inclusive. So we add +1 to make sure we print our the oreo.

Comment: The op's image shows they *do* need to enumerate the array.

Comment: He does:) The assignment says a numbered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to do it without a break.

Or if you have to use a `for` loop, you can set a flag like `fsnack_found == True` once you found the fsnack and just not print anything afterwards with some simple logic.

And of course compare `letter` to `fsnack`, not `snack` to `fsnack`:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag variable to keep track of when you found your snack.  Use it to skip over remaining items once you've found your snack.  You can also use it to signal that you haven't found your favorite snack at the end.

```
found = False 
for i,name in enumerate(snack,1):
    if not found:
        print(i,name)
        found = name == fsnack
if not found:
    print(fsnack,"not found!")
```